# Symfony3 deserialize multiple entity objects

Tags: serialization, symfony, php-7

Serialize and deserialize single entity object work properly for me.

It is possible to serialize and deserialize multiple object (array of objects) in this way??

```
$notifications = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Notification')
    ->findAll();

$encoder = new JsonEncoder();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($notifications, 'json');

return new Response($jsonContent);
```

And

```
$response = curl_exec($ch); // my $jsonContent from previous code

$encoder = new JsonEncoder();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$notifications = $serializer->deserialize($response, Notification::class, 'json');
```

Then i got:

> The property path constructor needs a string or an instance of
>   "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath". Got: "integer" 500
>   Internal Server Error - UnexpectedValueException

Comment: Will sounds stupid but the error message does tell you everything... Your property path constructor is waiting a an instance of `PropertyPath`, which is a child of [PropertyAccess](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html). But, your constructor get an Integer as parameter, which is obviously wrong. Can you add your construtor and everything related to it in your question plz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$serializer = new Serializer(
    array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer()),
    array(new JsonEncoder())
);

$data = ...; // The serialized data from the previous example
$persons = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Acme\Person[]', 'json');
```

Comment: Hello for people still hoping to use Symfony Serializer (and most of all deserializer), I found :
https://medium.com/@maartendeboer/using-the-symfony-serializer-with-doctrine-relations-69ecb17e6ebd